# How can I execute a C# code from Azure SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, calculated-columns

Considering the following C# code, I would like to know how can I use it to create a computed column so when querying I could do `SELECT ID, MaskedID FROM dbo.Product`

`ALTER TABLE dbo.Product ADD MaskedID AS (<Utils.Mask(ID) ???>) PERSISTED;`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Util {
    public string Mask(long id) {
       var maskedId = $"do-something-with-{id}"; // it's way more complex than this
       return maskedId;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot execute a C# code from Azure SQL Server you can execute SQL queries from C# to Azure SQL server.

Comment: I agree with @PratikLad. And maybe creating the Mask function as a sql function in the database would help solve your problem.

Comment: The C# masking method can not be translated into a SQL query. I asked about such a feature because [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b12021/invokeapp.htm) allows "invoke Java methods in classes that are loaded within the database, such as Java stored procedures."

Comment: Just found [Getting Started with CLR Integration
](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/getting-started-with-clr-integration?view=sql-server-ver16&viewFallbackFrom=azuresqldb-mi-current). I'll give a try and update this thread later.